# Jupyter notebook uploaded horizontally

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I was trying to upload one of my projects (with Jupiter notebook) on Github.

Out of seven files, one file is uploaded in horizontal format rather than vertical.

I deleted twice and reuploaded but the problem persists.

It might sound silly, but unable to figure out the actual problem.

Please view the attached image.

[image: jupyter notebook uploaded horizontally]